# Regex Wrapping Quotes

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I am trying to wrap quotes around certain section of content in a CSV file, the current layout is something like this:

```
 ###element1,element2,element3,element4,element5,element6,element7,element8, "element9,
element9,""element9"",element9,
element9,element9,""element9",element10,
###
```

the ### symbols depict a new line and each new line should have one, the problem is I need to get to all of element 9 in to one set of double quotes, however there are multiple instances of doublequotes within that area which break up the element in to new fields making my table expand beyond the fields I initially set. So I believe I need to remove all the " marks between the start and end of element9 and then reintroduce one set to highlight the whole section.

I approached this firstly by trying to select the 8th Comma from the start and the 2 comma from the end:

```
 ^((?:[^,]+,){8})(.+)((?:,[^,]*){2})$
```

and replacing with

```
$1"$2"$3
```

I tried to target the starting ### and ending ### to select those two elements but with no success.

any suggestions on how I can do this

**UPDATE**

```
    ###BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,BLAHBLAH,
BLAHBLAH,
BLAHBLAH,
BLAHBLAH, BLAHBLAH,
BLAHBLAH, BLAHBLAH,
BLAHBLAH,
"BLAHBLAH""",E,
###
```

The last field always seem to contain a capital letter, the fields before vary in quotation placement so to really target that whole section I need to work out how many commas along and how many back I need to go, remove the quotes and then reinstate them in the correct positions.

Comment: Could you paste a real sample of data? In my opinion, the csv format is probably correct since `""` is an escaped quote in a quoted field. To avoid problems reading your csv file, use a csv parser.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, it's confidential! That's why I had to substitute it in. there are only 10 column headings, so the extra lines must have got append on a newline and commas added. This is making my database think there are X amount more fields than there actually should be

Comment: In this case, post a real row where you replace "confidential" informations but don't touch to the quotes.

Comment: Let me mock something up might take a few minutes

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: MySQL is the database

Comment: Couple of question - What are you trying to do? ;) In the original query you seem to be after quoting the 9th field, in the update the 17th. (And those are the only fields already quoted...(?).) And - what's notepad++ got to do with it?

Comment: There are 10 fields/headings, element number 9 has spanned across several lines so the data is not complete on the one line (there are multiple instances of this through the records of varying sizes) so I need to get all of the spanned elements and concatenate them in to one quoted string which will make up element 9. Notepad is what I am using to do the regex. So my question is really what regex would get me the content after the 8th comma and before the 2nd comma from the end so I can remove all the quotes then put them back around the whole element. Hope that clears it up

Comment: @DanW: I can suggest a 2-pass solution: 1) [`(^\s*#{3}(?:[^,]*,){8}[^"]*|(?!^)\G)"([^"]*)"(?=(?:(?!#{3}).)*,[^,]*,[^,]*#{3}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/qQ8nW1/2) (with `. matches newline` on) and replace with `$1$2`, (this regex assumes the number of quotes is even, see [this one](https://regex101.com/r/qQ8nW1/4) if the number of quotes is unknown), 2) adding quotes with [`(^\s*#{3}(?:[^,]*,){8}\s*)((?:(?!#{3}).)*)(?=(?:(?!#{3}).)*,[^,]*,[^,]*#{3}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/qQ8nW1/3) and replace with `$1"$2"`. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: You should not remove any commas unless it's certain that none of your **BLAHBLAH** nor **elementX** contain a comma for e.g. **BLAHBLAH**  = "**1,2,3,4**" or "BLAH, BLAH"  or  **elementX** = "**Oh!, here's a comma**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
###(?:[^,]*,){8}\K([\s\S]*?)(?=,[^,]*,[^,]*?###)
```

Try this.Replace by `"\1"` or `"$1"`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/13

Comment: As we speak I have solved my issue another way, however I took a look at your demo and it seems like it does exactly what I wanted so I'll mark your answer correct! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
/^(?:[^,]*,){8}([^#]*),[^,]*,[^,]*$/s
```

https://regex101.com/r/hU8yO6/1

I think the regexp you had is about right, except for needing the /s modifier.

For notepad++, get the s modifier by ticking ". matches newline":

```
^(?:[^,]*,){8}([^#]*),[^,]*,[^,]*$
```

This looks like a good reference: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

You'll probably want to add parens appropriately to make capture groups also.

Comment: on your example it works exactly as I was hoping, however trying to put it in to notepad++ it throws an error "Can't find the text /^(?:[^,]*,){8}(.*),[^,]*,[^,]*$/s" any ideas?

Comment: same issue with your second version, can't find the text (?:s)^(?:[^,]*,){8}(.*),[^,]*,[^,]*$

Comment: You have the Extended option selected?

Comment: Copied exactly your regex. Initially had Regex mode ticked, tried extended also threw the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Getting rid of the leading `(?:s)`, I am getting a match just fine: http://i.imgur.com/GbfnU7c.png  (don't forget to tick `. matches newline`)

Comment: getting rid of that leading symbol basically highlights everything I need and the rest of my 500k+ records. I think I need some way of getting the start and end of the line using the ### symbols

Comment: The `.*` is probably running away. Try changing the `.` to `[^#]`. I have updated the answer above accordingly.

Answer (score -4):

```
^#+[^"]+"([^#]+),[^,]+,[^,]+###\s*$
```

Comment: While this regex may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.