# Regex Notepad++ Finding, Removing and Replacing Quotations

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have some content in a CSV file which I need to format correctly, the content layout goes like this :

```
###Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,
Field8,
Field8,
Field8, Field8,
Field8, Field8,
Field8,
"Field8""",Field9,
###
```

As you can see Field 8 Spans multiple lines and has quotes and commas within which seems to break it in to new fields. What I need is a Regex which will identify the 9th Comma in from the start of the line which is ### for each line. and then go from the end ### back 2 commas. I need to then be able to format everything in that area across all records that match, remove all the quote marks just in that area and add them back in at the start and end, effectively wrapping the quotes round the whole of Field 8.

The triple **#** symbol is present in the file and I would need to use this as a reference to find the start of each record.

I have a Regex which seemed to work previously doing something similar but now does not as the format of the CSV has changed from file to file.

```
 ^((?:[^,]+,){8})(.+)((?:,[^,]*){2})$ and replace with $1"$2"$3
```

Comment: Last time you asked this question (hmm... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145507/regex-wrapping-quotes) the first field came directly after `###`. Which is it? Because if you remove the first `,` your re works.

Comment: Sorry i will amend the question, the first field does come directly after the ###.

Comment: What string do you want to get in a result?

Comment: So all of the Field8 Elements wrapped in one set of quotes. It has to use the ### as the start and end of a record, and use commas identify the position, so Field8 starts at 7th comma position and ends at 2nd comma position from the end.